# Select tag is not displaying the item correctly

Tags: html, input, html-select

I am using many select tag to show many items but problem is that it not displaying the full text. The text appear to be cut, i am not using any css on it. What may be the problem with that.

On selecting everything is fine but before selection text is shown half.
image for that is below[image]

Comment: When your select element looks like this you definitely use some styling..

Comment: What's your browser and OS? Are there any zoom or font increase settings in the browser?

Comment: Look familiar? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/sk8cd/

Comment: @KenstonChoi - That's IE (9?). See my fiddle in IE and that's the only browser I found with that down arrow style on the `select`.

Comment: If fixed height need to be used, you have to make it large enough for the padding and the text line height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/sk8cd/1/

All you had to do is get rid of the padding and change the height.